# React prettifying URLs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My company has urls like this:

```
    http://helloworld.com/product?filter[category][0]=persian
```

We want the url to look like this:

```
    http://helloworld.com/product-persian
```

When a filter is applied to the current url it looks like this:

```
    http://helloworld.com/product?filter[category][0]=persian&filter[style][0]=border
```

We'd like the filters to stay the same. so the new url we'd like would show this:

```
    http://helloworld.com/product-persian&filter[style][0]=border
```

Using react, is there an optimal native way of doing this? I've briefly looked into `https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/10-clean-urls` and briefly into redis. What are the methods you use to do this when working with the react framework?

Answer (score 0):

To use URLs like these: 
`http://helloworld.com/product-persian`, react-router is good option.

Write it like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

const Routes = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return(
       <Router history={ browserHistory }>
         <Route path='/home' component={ homeComponent }/>
         <Route path='/product' component={ productsComponent }>
           <Route path='/product-:productName' component={ sigleProductComponent }/> {/* Single product route */}
           <Route path='/product-:productName&filter=:filterData' component={ productsComponent }/> {/* Product with filter params route */}
         </Route>
       </Router>
    )
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(<Routes />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

In this code example you use `params` on urls, to call this prop use `this.props.params.productName` or `this.props.params.filterData` in your component `sigleProductComponent`.

This props are pass from `react-router` component.

I hope this code helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your response! getting back to this after a few days of doing another project. We are already using react-router, and have some of your suggestions already in place. the `:productName` for example. We'd like to remove the `&filter=` from the uri and replace it with the name of the filter parameter on specific instances. looking at what you provided (thank you again) it looks like we'd still get the `?filter...` to show up. am I looking at this incorrectly?